# Using different proxies on different WebBrowsers simultaneously

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, proxy

as the title I was wondering if there was a method to use different proxy on various WebBrowser simultaneously.
At first I tried to insert 5 WebBrowser and create 5 threads, and each performs this sub (which I found on the internet) to change proxy:

```
Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Public dwAccessType As Integer
    Public proxy As IntPtr
    Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure

Private Declare Auto Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean

Private Sub RefreshIESettings(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3
    Dim s_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    s_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    s_IPI.proxy = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    s_IPI.proxyBypass = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Global")
    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s_IPI))
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(s_IPI, intptrStruct, True)
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s_IPI))
End Sub
```

but it was a failure because the ip was found to be the same or in some cases were the same and 4 ip 1 different.

Comment: I have been able to achieve this with Awesomium. You could try it too.

Comment: Can you tell me more precisely how you did? I just downloaded and installed Awesomium

Comment: A webControl is the equivalent of the WebBrowser control. The WebControl has a WebSession property that is set at instantiation.  

The websession in turn has a WebPreferences property that has a ProxyConfig property that describes the proxy settings.

You should make a new websession for each of your webcontrols, and assign a different webpreferences object for each one, having set the proxy trough proxyconfig.

See this: http://is.gd/99Absf

And this: http://is.gd/XAqMpG

Comment: I have see the links but i'm programmin in visual basic not in C#, anyway i I tried this code:

Dim WebPreferences1 As Awesomium.Core.WebPreferences
WebPreferences1.ProxyConfig = "218.108.170.172:82"
WebControl1.WebSession=WebCore.CreateWebSession(WebControl1.WebSession.DataPath.ToString, WebPreferences1)
WebControl1.Source = New Uri("http://www.whatismyip.com/")

but it not work

Comment: c# methods and properties are the exact same ones you call in vb. you can try with the designer(no code): add a websessionprovider from the toolbox in your form1. there you set the proxy in the webpreferences in the property pane. then add a webcontrol to the form, and set its websessionprovider to the one you just configured. this should work to illustrate the idea

Comment: ps. have you checked the proxy?
http://www.checker.freeproxy.ru/checker/ says it is dead.

Comment: I solved it by creating the webcontrol from code, now I need to know how to create the webcontrol from code with a thread.
If i try to do it appears this error "Controls created on one thread can not have as a parent control on a different thread."

Comment: you could setup the controls on the form and then do calls from a BackgroundWorker

Comment: even with BackgroundWorker appears the same error

Comment: create the controls from the form normally, then drive them with threads/backgroundworkers

Comment: thank you I solved it with a InvokeRequired, but now I need to know  when the Awesomium WebControl have fully loaded the url.. there is a event for that or a value in its proprieties ?

Comment: yes, you have to monitor `WebControl.DocumentReady(sender As Object, e As Awesomium.Core.DocumentReadyEventArgs)`

Comment: I am using this code: 'While WebControl1.IsDocumentReady = False
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While'
to wait until the page is loaded, it is right ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: Can i change the proxy of one WebControl without deleting and re-create it ??

Comment: I don't think so, since you can't assign a new websession to a webcontrol

Comment: You know how can suppress this message of WebBrowser ?
http://grabilla.com/04c19-6664d9e3-1828-497c-b4fd-a1caa1107a83.html

Comment: Have a [thorough look at the documentation](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=Events_T_Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl), and you shall find the most suitable event to be handled.

Comment: "Internal Server Error"

Comment: That is beyond the scope of your question, as it is an error that comes from a faulty server you reached with the proxy, or from the proxy itsef. Anyway, [here is its meaning](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500_it.html). I have already selected the language for you as we both speak Italian (or at least, your OS does).

Comment: in this site http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=Events_T_Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl appear "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Where? http://i.imgur.com/PUIojKn.png